# Field recording with android phone and external preamp/help testing

Tags: android, field-recording

So i will be upgrading my phone soon(galaxy s3), and yesterday i found this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.usbaudiorecorderpro&hl=lt
and to my surprise in compatibility list(http://www.extreamsd.com/USBAudioRecorderPRO/) i found that sound devices mixpre-d works with this app, the problem is they don't tell what phone they used to test this...maybe someone that has s3 and mixpre-d can download trial version of the app, and confirm if it works or not? :)

Answer (score 1):

chances are it does work since its a top of the line device

i have been looking into using microphones with android, i was able to plug in a guitar straight in through the headphone jack and record it as well as use a microphone to record using several patch cables so you really dont even need a usb soundcard

Answer (score 1):

You can ask someone with Galaxy S3 to check the app page on Google Play Store to see if the app is listed compatible. Google Play Store warns and doesn't allow an install if the app is incompatible.

For my Samsung Galaxy Tab S T700 tablet, Google Play Store says it is compatible with the device. It also says it is incompatible with my HTC phone. So the compatibility info should be somehow reliable.

In any case, you should email and ask the developer directly before making an investment on it. Their email is listed on app's Google Play page.